# Firebase dynamic links not tracking app installs

Tags: android, firebase

[Dynamic links screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrqCj.png)

[image]

This is the screenshot of my dynamic links.
As you can see, the link has been clicked quite a lot, 
but the chart indicates 0 app installs, 0 first-opens.

yet there are 3 re-opens.

Also, on the same projects, for the same duration,
the first-open as a whole is recorded 
[firebase analytics - events screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvxhm.png)

[image]

so the first-open event does work.

Only the first-open events using dynamic links don't seem to work. 
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: sorry no answer, but I do have the same issue as you.

Answer (score 3):

I got answers from Google team.

To summarize, did you incorporate dynamic Links SDK into your app?

---

To receive data being passed to your Dynamic Links, you need to include the Dynamic Links SDK in your app and call the methods FirebaseDynamicLinks.getDynamicLink() for Android, and handleUniversalLink: and dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL: for iOS.

Note that these methods should be called at every entry point in your app that will be launched by the link.